# QT Console Application in Lubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

I'm trying to write a console app in Qt under Lubuntu.

But when I'm trying to run something, i.e.:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    cout << " hello world";
    return a.exec();
}
```

it fails, saying :

> "Cannot change to working directory home/myusername/myproject: no such
>   a file or directory".

But this directory exists, there's even the build file in it, marked as executable. But when I trying to run it from the terminal, the response is: `myproject-console is not a command.`

What happened to "Hello, World!" app? Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your application tries to look for a **relative** path `home/myusername/myproject` and not for the **absolute** path `/home/myusername/myproject`. Have you checked the path contained in `argv`?

Comment: I can't. It says: The gdb process has not responded to a command within 40 second(s). This could mean it is stuck in an endless loop or taking longer than expected to perform the operation.
You can choose between waiting longer or abort debugging.

Comment: Well, can you access the process you are trying to execute?